# Cannot perform a handshake with google`s cloud speech-to-text on ESP32. [PK - The pubkey tag or value is invalid (only RSA and EC are supported)]

Tags: c++, esp32, google-speech-api, google-cloud-speech, esp8266wifi

I am trying to establish a connection with speech.googleapis.com. I am using the code from https://github.com/MhageGH/esp32_CloudSpeech/tree/master/esp32_CloudSpeech. I modified the network_param.h, so that certificate is set right. I also created the ApiKey on google cloud and added it to the network_param.h.

I try to create CloudSpeechClient() using the API enum.
`CloudSpeechClient* cloudSpeechClient = new CloudSpeechClient(USE_APIKEY);`

I am stuck with this error saying that pubkey tag or value is invalid.

```
[  1062][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 0 - WIFI_READY
[  1151][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:340] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Started
[  1155][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 2 - STA_START
[  1166][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:97] set_esp_interface_ip(): Configuring Station static IP: 0.0.0.0, MASK: 0.0.0.0, GW: 0.0.0.0
[  3039][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:362] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Disconnected: SSID: AndroidAP_2200, BSSID: f6:03:d0:52:38:e8, Reason: 202
[  3040][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 5 - STA_DISCONNECTED
[  3047][W][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1057] _eventCallback(): Reason: 202 - AUTH_FAIL
[  3054][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1077] _eventCallback(): WiFi Reconnect Running
[  3075][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:97] set_esp_interface_ip(): Configuring Station static IP: 0.0.0.0, MASK: 0.0.0.0, GW: 0.0.0.0
[  3811][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:355] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Connected: SSID: AndroidAP_2200, BSSID: f6:03:d0:52:38:e8, Channel: 11, Auth: WPA2_PSK
[  3814][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 4 - STA_CONNECTED
[  3862][V][WiFiGeneric.cpp:369] _arduino_event_cb(): STA Got New IP:192.168.78.11
[  3863][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1035] _eventCallback(): Arduino Event: 7 - STA_GOT_IP
[  3866][D][WiFiGeneric.cpp:1098] _eventCallback(): STA IP: 192.168.78.11, MASK: 255.255.255.0, GW: 192.168.78.68
[  4376][V][ssl_client.cpp:62] start_ssl_client(): Free internal heap before TLS 103340
[  4377][V][ssl_client.cpp:68] start_ssl_client(): Starting socket
[  4478][V][ssl_client.cpp:146] start_ssl_client(): Seeding the random number generator
[  4480][V][ssl_client.cpp:155] start_ssl_client(): Setting up the SSL/TLS structure...
[  4484][V][ssl_client.cpp:178] start_ssl_client(): Loading CA cert
[  4495][V][ssl_client.cpp:254] start_ssl_client(): Setting hostname for TLS session...
[  4497][V][ssl_client.cpp:269] start_ssl_client(): Performing the SSL/TLS handshake...
[  4594][E][ssl_client.cpp:37] _handle_error():[start_ssl_client():273]: (-15104) PK - The pubkey tag or value is invalid (only RSA and EC are supported)
[  4597][E][WiFiClientSecure.cpp:144] connect(): start_ssl_client: -15104
[  4605][V][ssl_client.cpp:321] stop_ssl_socket(): Cleaning SSL connection.
```

Not sure how to format it in a better way - maybe image will be better. [Traces in image format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iOC9A.png)

I tried changing the certificate and re-generating the API code. I tried puuting less restriction on the API key. I expected it to connect smoothly :/.